# infinite loop when redirect

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, cookies

When redirect to my home page I have an infinite loop. For example is http://mydomain.com then when redirect using javascript 
url = 'home/request_verification' ;
window.location = url;

my url now becomes http://mydomain.com/home/request_verfication then http://mydomain.com/home/home/request_verification and so on. It always added home class.

I just used this script

```
function checkCookie() {
var mob_tel=getCookie("mob_tel");
if (mob_tel!=null && mob_tel!="") {
    //alert("Welcome again " + mob_tel);
    url = "home/test";
    window.location = url;
    //window.location.href('home/checkbalance');
} else {
    set_name("");
}
}
```

then in my body

```
<body onload="checkCookie()">
 ...........
 ................
</body>
```

Help anyone..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`home/test` is a relative url. You're probably in need of an absolute url `/home/test`.

The difference is that `home/` looks for `home` in the current folder, but `/home` looks for `home` in the *root* of your website.

Comment: change my code to url: home/check_balance to /home/check_balance now an infinite refresh. It acts like the page is always refreshing. you can access my site here: apps.stratpoint.com:9114/

Comment: Does `/home/test` set a cookie? If the cookie isn't set, then it will redirect indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

You got to use the absolute path, else the infinite loop continues.
So, use

```
url = "http://mydomain.com/home/test";
window.location = url;
```

If you do not want to hardcode the root URL ie.,http://mydomain.com, try getting the root directory of the site from the server side like $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] in PHP as shown below:

```
url = "http://"+"<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];?>"+"/home/test"; (for localhost) and
url = "<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];?>"+"/home/test"; (for urls already containing http://)

window.location = url;
```